# Access PhpStorm web server (Laravel) via LAN

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I have a Laravel Project that I develop in PhpStorm. I use the build in PhpStorm web server for development and debugging. (`localhost:8000`) Now I need to be able to access that server from another device within the same network.

Google search and jetbrains.com have not been very helpful. I have tried this (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207020155-phpstorm-and-http-server-localhost-only-) but it did not work.

Any help?

**EDIT**:
I found the problem. Since the web server is launched via `artisan`, it ignores my PhpStorm settings. I needed to change the launch parameter, like so:

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want.

Comment: I do not see a PhpStorm issue here. PhpStorm's built-in web server has no relation to what `artisan serve` does.